# Overriding transitive dependency version in library's pom doesn't override version in pom using the library

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

Sorry for the confusing title but it would be easier if I drew a dependency chart

```
lib-a (v1a)
  \_lib-b
     \_lib-c (v1c)

lib-d
  \_ lib-a (v1a)
```

I have a use case like this, and I'm trying to override the version of lib-c to v2c in lib-a jar and lib-d jar

So in pom.xml for lib-a, I have excluded lib-c and added lib-c as dependency with version v2c

But when the lib-a is being used in lib-d it still shows the version of lib-c to be v1c, is that how it supposed to be? Shouldn't the override in lib-a's pom override the version of lib-c in lib-a's users? Is the only way out is override lib-c again in lib-d's pom?

Comment: Have you defined the dep for lib-c (v2c) before the lib-b dependency in your pom file? (BTW: The exclusions is not necessary)... ?

Comment: Yes @khmarbaise, I did declare lib-c (v2c) dependency before lib-b in the pom.xml and yet when I used it in lib-d it still makes use of lib-c (v1c). The reason I'm excluding lib-c (v1c) cause I am making use of enforcer plugin and it gives a conflict otherwise.

Comment: When I used dependency resolver in IntelliJ I get that lib-c is making use of lib-c (v2c) but on using dependency resolver for lib-d it shows it is making use of lib-a with lib-c (v1c)

Comment: Please make an example project on github or alike... otherwise it's hard to follow etc. In what way are you using the maven-enforcer-plugin? etc.